# How to track head position and rotation with kinect sdk?

Tags: sdk, rotation, position, kinect, head

I wonder how I can track the head position and rotation with kinect sdk! 
Is it possible? If yes how?

And whatabout tracking the entire body rotation?? (y-axis)

Please c# code would be grateful ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely Kinect SDK provides head rotation against X, Y, and Z axis using **Face Tracking**.

- In **OnFrameReady** method, please construct FaceTracker object with Kinect Sensor as its parameter.

> `this.faceTracker = new FaceTracker(kinectSensor);`

- Create FaceTrackFrame object using **.Track()** method of **facetracker**.

> ```
> FaceTrackFrame frame = this.faceTracker.Track(colorImageFormat, colorImage, depthImageFormat, depthImage, skeletonOfInterest);
> ```

- Get X, Y , Z head rotation axis :

> float yRotation = frame.Rotation.Y;
>
> float xRotation = frame.Rotation.X;
>
> float zRotation = frame.Rotation.Z;

FYI about head rotation using Face Tracking, here is the documentation :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx

About body rotation, I haven't tried any experiment on it.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there isn't a way to track rotation. The best way you could go about doing so would be to compare the Left Shoulder and Right Shoulder, or the Left Hip and Right Hip, and determine each Z axis to see which is closer and then you can get an idea of which way the body is rotated.